# member access to wrapper class without runtime pointers

Tags: c++

I want to be able to extend my coroutine class with variable number
of "i/o pins", but these need access to the main class.
Also I don't want to add extra pointers to pin objects, mainly
because its hard to find a place to initialize them properly.
So I kinda found one workaround:

```
template< int base_offs > struct pin {
  int y1;
  void test( void );
};

template< class pin1, class pin2 > struct wrap0 {
  int x1;
  char x2;
  pin1 r3;
  pin2 r4;
};

template< int base_offs >
void pin<base_offs>::test( void ) {
  typedef wrap0< pin<0>,pin<0> > wrap;
  wrap& W = *(wrap*)(((char*)this)-base_offs);
  printf( "y1=%i W.x1=%i W.x2=%i\n", y1, W.x1, W.x2 );
}

typedef wrap0< pin<0>,pin<0> > wrap1;

typedef wrap0< pin< offsetof(wrap1,r3) >, pin< offsetof(wrap1,r4) > > wrap;

wrap Z = {456,123,33333,44444};

int main( void ) {
  Z.r3.test();
  Z.r4.test();
}
```

VC build: http://rextester.com/MXO25153

gcc build: http://ideone.com/987JP5

Now, questions:

1. Is there a way to compute offsetof during initial class declaration?
   (ie like this: http://ideone.com/tomF0T)
2. Is there a better *compile-time* solution to the wrapper-access problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's another version, probably final one, because
its compatible with both VC and gcc, and doesn't really
have any annoying side effects.
Sure, a function is not normally "compile-time", but in
this case its inlined and optimized to constants anyway.

```
template< class wrap, int (*base_offs)(void) > struct pin {
  int y1;
  void test( void ) {
    wrap& W = *(wrap*)(((char*)this) - ((*base_offs)()) );
    printf( "ofs=%i y1=%i W.x1=%i W.x2=%i\n", ((*base_offs)()), y1, W.x1, W.x2 );
  }
};

struct wrap {
  int x1;
  char x2;
  static int get_r3(void) { return offsetof(wrap,r3); }
  pin< wrap, get_r3 > r3;
  static int get_r4(void) { return offsetof(wrap,r4); }
  pin< wrap, get_r4 > r4;
};

wrap Z = {456,123,33333,44444};

int main( void ) {
  Z.r3.test();
  Z.r4.test();
}
```

VC: http://rextester.com/NPBY12766
gcc: http://rextester.com/XWI48752

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one version, but VC doesn't support it.
IntelC and gcc do though.

```
template< class wrap, class pad, pad wrap::*X > struct pin {
  int y1;
  void test( void ) {
    wrap& W = *(wrap*)(((char*)this) - size_t(&(((wrap*)0)->*X)) - sizeof(pad));
    printf( "y1=%i W.x1=%i W.x2=%i\n", y1, W.x1, W.x2 );
  }
};

struct wrap {
  int x1;
  char x2;
  typedef pin< wrap, char, &wrap::x2 > r3_t;
  r3_t r3;
  typedef pin< wrap, r3_t, &wrap::r3 > r4_t;
  r4_t r4;
};

wrap Z = {456,123,33333,44444};

int main( void ) {
  Z.r3.test();
  Z.r4.test();
}
```

VC: http://rextester.com/QFY31637
gcc: http://rextester.com/HEN91787